# Can Serilog destructure complex objects passed to BeginScope?

Tags: serilog, microsoft-extensions-logging

I'm using **Serilog.Extensions.Logging** and outputting to console with this outputTemplate:

`"{Timestamp:HH:mm} [{Level:u3}] {Message} {Properties:j} {NewLine}"`

What I would like to see, is that complex objects set via `BeginScope` get destructured into `Properties`. Instead, it seems, the type name is used.

```
var data = new Data { Id = 42, Name = "Hitchhiker" };
using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Data", data } }))
{
    logger.LogInformation("Hello world!");
}
```

The result is:

`10:40 [INF] Hello world! {"SourceContext": "ConsoleApp3.Program", "Data": "ConsoleApp3.Data"}`

What I want is:

`10:40 [INF] Hello world! {"SourceContext": "ConsoleApp3.Program", "Data": { "Id" = 42, "Name" = "Hitchhiker"} }`

Am I missing a configuration setting, or is this simply not possible?

**edit**

Just noticed that this can be accomplished by vanilla Serilog:

`var dataLogger = logger.ForContext("Data", data, true);`

Here the last parameter informs Serilog that it should destructure the complex type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The complex type will get destructured if the key is prefixed with an `@` character.
So:

`using (logger.BeginScope(new Dictionary<string, object> { { "@Data", data } }))`

does the trick :-)

Comment: Is there no other way to configure that globally? This kinda is leaking internals, cause if you'd switch logger implementation, you'd have to change these too everywhere right?